# Outlook macro to check end of the month and weekends

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

We have a outlook macro which sends reports to users from Monday to Friday.

But now they ask for a requirement where if the End of the Month is on a Saturday or Sunday, then the report should be sent too.

Is there any method we can achieve this in a single statement, without writing a separate function

Answer (score 0):

i would use something like

```
if month(now()+1) <> month(now()) then sendthereport
```

but it would be easier to post a specific answer knowing your code...

Max